# How modify some x-axis values in a .fig file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a .fig file that i want to modify just 2 values in x-axis.

How is it possible when i do not have the source code of plotting? There is just a .fig file.

Comment: Modify the labels or the actual values?

Comment: @LuisMendo Actual values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling the data out with `get(gca,...)` is probably the most direct solution.  However, there is some other obscure but useful MATLAB functionality worth mentioning.

The first is the ability of MATLAB to generate M-files from figures, which can be used to recreate and modify a figure programmatically. Just click the following menu item and you will get a new function in the editor like `function createfigure(X1, Y1)` that will exactly recreate the figure, but with some new data `X1` and `Y1`.

[image]

The other thing worth mention is that .fig files are really MAT-files containing data specifying the figure. For instance, the following commands will load the .fig data into a `struct` in MATLAB and you can access the plot data easily:

```
>> f = load('testjunk.fig','-mat')
f = 
    hgS_070000: [1x1 struct]
>> axesNum = 1; seriesNum = 1;
>> series = f.hgS_070000.children(axesNum).children(seriesNum)
series = 
          type: 'graph2d.lineseries'
        handle: 172.0051
    properties: [1x1 struct]
      children: []
       special: []
>> X1 = series.properties.XData
ans =
    0.0305    0.7441    0.5000    0.4799    0.9047
>> Y1 = series.properties.YData
ans =
    0.6099    0.6177    0.8594    0.8055    0.5767
```

Mix and match to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments: you have one pair of *x*- and *y*-axes, with several plots in it, and you want to modify the *values*.

Open the .fig file and do:

```
aux = get(gca,'Children'); %// get all plots within current axes
n = 1; %// or 2 or 3, whichever plot you want to change
x = get(aux(n),'XData'); %// x values of selected plot
```

This will give you the *x*-axis values in variable `x`. Modify that variable as needed, and then put it back into the plot:

```
set(aux(n),'XData',x)
```

Comment: I have a plot with three sub-figure. I get this error: Error using get
Invalid property found.
Object Name :  text
Property Name :  'XData'.

Comment: I mean no subplot. sub-figures. three polynomial functions in a plot.