# Processing loaded Matlab figure data in the workspace

Tags: matlab

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/249507). 
I have data in the fig -file:

[image]

I run

```
s = load('filename.fig','-mat');
```

I get many fields of data:

[image]

I would like to get data only in the range from -1.5 to 2 in a list.

**How can you retrieve data from such a Matlab data-structure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hinted at this process in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19745791/2778484) to a different question. As you know, .fig files are actually MAT-files that contain data which specifies the figure. To load the .fig data into a MATLAB `struct` and then access the `XData` and `YData` properties of a specific axes and series (you can have multiple axes and series):

```
>> s = load('filename.fig','-mat');
s = 
    hgS_070000: [1x1 struct]
>> axesNum = 1; seriesNum = 1;
>> series = s.hgS_070000.children(axesNum).children(seriesNum)
series = 
          type: 'graph2d.lineseries'
        handle: 172.0051
    properties: [1x1 struct]
      children: []
       special: []
>> XData = series.properties.XData;
>> YData = series.properties.YData;
```

Now you just have to grab the samples you want:

```
rangeMask = YData >= -1.5 & YData <= 2;
YDataSub = YData(rangeMask);
XDataSub = XData(rangeMask);
```

See also [this examination of the .fig file format](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format/), for a simplified example with only one axis and one series, thus not using any `axesNum` and `seriesNum` indexes.

Comment: Thank you for very much for your fast answer!